# How to connect to Aurora Mysql 3 clone?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I just cloned my Aurora MySQL 2 RDS db, then upgraded the hardware and updated it to Aurora MySQL 3. My application can connect just fine, but I cannot connect to the clone to view anything.

Does anybody know if the security is different between versions 2 and 3, or what I have to do to get in there? I see that the master user/password are the same, I tried resetting it regardless and I still can't get in.